# Project 3D polygon into a 2D plane such that the vertices are in counter clockwise order

Tags: algorithm, math, polygon, basis

Some fast algorithms for working with polygons require the vertices of the polygon to have a specific order (clockwise or counter clockwise with respect to the polygon's plane normal).

To use those algorithms in 3D planar polygons (where all the points lie in a particular plane) one can perform a change of basis [to a basis spanned by two orthogonal vectors that lie in the plane and a plane normal vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345/32393).

Is there a way to always find a basis in which the polygon vertices are always in counter clockwise (or clockwise) order?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best method is to compute the [signed area of the polygon](http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html), and if it is negative, you know your vertices are clockwise; so reverse. If it is positive, your vertices are counterclockwise.

Search for "signed area of polygon." Here is one [Mathematica link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SignedAreaOfAPolygon/):

---

[image: SignedArea]

---